# Poor internet performance on single PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have been having a frustrating issue with my main desktop for the last few days, that I was hoping someone could shed a light on.

I have 3 devices in my house, a laptop, a mac, and a PC.  My laptop and mac are preforming fine, with results from http://speedtest.xfinity.com/ displaying download speeds of 120~ Mbps.  However, my PC has been stuck at .5-1.5 Mbps, making it difficult to stream HD videos or play online games.

Looking at the speed on the connection's network status, I am seeing around 72 Mbps.

I have already done a malware/anti-virus scan, but I won't have an Ethernet cable to test with until the beginning of the week. I've also already checked with my ISP, and they don't see anything fishy on their end.

FYI, My wireless adapter is a DW1501 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card

Comment: We can rule out your service to the house, since there is good service to two other devices.  You also need to tell us what router you are using.

Comment: Get or borrow a UTP cable and connect your PC to the router by wire. If the performance is better, it's the WiFi. You can also try to move the PC closer to the router, be careful not to break anything.